Simulation of click on a toolbar in another program c#
I want open dialog in another program (ezcad) using sendMessage in c# (
it must be in the background).
manual dialog opening options:

ctrl + H (no working via postMessage)
click button in toolbar (ToolbarWindow32) - spy++ it doesn't read the name of the button, only the entire bar
click menu: Edit -> Hatch

Are there any other ways to stop the dialog from opening in the background?
